# Docker ( x86-cross) building fails when running cpan after macOS update 14.1.1

Tags: docker, macos, dockerfile

I updated the macOS-M1 system to 14.1.1

and

`Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc`

all of a sudden a docker cross build fails on AMD64 but works on ARM64.
In the past (before updates) both architectures where building fine, so something there has changed.

I'm using:

```
build --cache-from thiloj/documentix:buildcache-amd64 --platform=linux/amd64 --cache-to thiloj/documentix:buildcache-amd64 -t t1/test:latest -f Dockerfile.t --load .
```

with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN  apt-get -y install \
        git \
        make \
        gcc \
        wget \

ENV LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
RUN cpan CPAN
```

Any cpan installs fails with an error message about expanding the Makefile.PL like below:

```
[+] Building 34.0s (8/8) FINISHED                                                                            docker-container:multi-platform-builder
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.t                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.62kB                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04                                                                                 0.5s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => importing cache manifest from thiloj/documentix:buildcache-amd64                                                                            0.7s
 => => inferred cache manifest type: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                                                                    0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:2b7412e6465c3c7fc5bb21d3e6f1917c167358449fecac8176c6e496e5c1f05f                           0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:2b7412e6465c3c7fc5bb21d3e6f1917c167358449fecac8176c6e496e5c1f05f                           0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] RUN apt-get update --fix-missing                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN  apt-get -y install  git  make  gcc  wget                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN cpan CPAN                                                                                                                  32.7s
------                                                                                                                                               
 > [4/4] RUN cpan CPAN:                                                                                                                              
0.899 Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging                                                                          
0.900                                                                                                                                                
0.900 CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done automatically.                                                                      
0.900 If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive dialog for each                                                                        
0.900 configuration option instead.
0.900 
0.900 Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes] yes
0.985 Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
0.985 http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
1.155 Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
1.888 ............................................................................DONE
2.432 Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
2.432 http://www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
2.674 Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
4.553   Database was generated on Sun, 19 Nov 2023 20:17:01 GMT
4.553   HTTP::Date not available
4.554 ..............
7.931   New CPAN.pm version (v2.36) available.
7.931   [Currently running version is v2.28]
7.931   You might want to try
7.931     install CPAN
7.931     reload cpan
7.931   to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
7.931   the current session.
7.931 
7.931 
8.131 ..............................................................DONE
23.64 Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
23.64 http://www.cpan.org/modules/03modlist.data.gz
23.70 Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
23.71 DONE
23.71 Writing /root/.cpan/Metadata
25.18 Running install for module 'CPAN'
25.20 Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
25.20 http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-2.36.tar.gz
25.38 Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
25.38 http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CHECKSUMS
25.63 Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-2.36.tar.gz ok
25.87 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
26.20 Configuring A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-2.36.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
26.95 Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
26.95 Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
31.01   Database was generated on Sun, 19 Nov 2023 20:17:01 GMT
31.01 >(error): Could not expand [Makefile.PL]. Check the module name.
31.01 >(info): I can suggest names if you install one of Text::Levenshtein::XS, Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::XS, Text::Levenshtein, and Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::PP
31.01 >(info): and you provide the -x option on invocation.
31.01 >(error): Skipping Makefile.PL because I couldn't find a matching namespace.
31.01 >(error): Could not expand [INSTALLDIRS=site]. Check the module name.
31.01 >(error): Skipping INSTALLDIRS=site because I couldn't find a matching namespace.
31.77 No 'Makefile' created  ANDK/CPAN-2.36.tar.gz
31.77   /usr/bin/cpan Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
------
Dockerfile.t:11
--------------------
   9 |          wget 
  10 |     
  11 | >>> RUN cpan CPAN
  12 |     
  13 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/dev/.buildkit_qemu_emulator /bin/sh -c cpan CPAN" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Strange enough, if I run the cpan command manually in the container instead from the Dockerfile it works.

I did not find any hints on what is wrong or how to further trace the problem.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/464

Comment: Unlikely, 4 years ago and the emulator works. I can connect and run my commands.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I forgot to (re-) install emulators...
https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/

$ docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all

Did solve my problem.

@drum, thank for giving me the chance to search again at the known docker issues!